# FluentValidation on Collection in Non-Wrapper Class in C#

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Every time I see `FluentValidation` upon a collection, there's a wrapper class around the list like below in A.  The problem with the wrapper class is that the collection has to be assigned to a field name, but I want my request to look like: `[{}, {}]` rather than: `{fooBars: [{},{}]}`. The FooBar validator doesn't seem to know how to validate a List of FooBar on its own.

How can I ensure validation on a List of FooBar without assigning the list to a field in the request?

```
A. 
public async Task<IActionResult> PostFooBarsAsync(Foos request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
```

where

```
public class Foos{
  public List<FooBar> FooBars { get; set; } = new List<FooBar>();
}
```

and

```
 public class FoosValidator : AbstractValidator<Foos> {
   public FoosValidator() {
    RuleForEach(x => x.FooBars).SetValidator(new FooBarValidator());
  }
}
```

Vs.

```
B.
public async Task<IActionResult> PostFooBarAsync(List<FooBar> request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = 
default(CancellationToken))
```

with validator

```
public class FooBarValidator : AbstractValidator<FooBar>
{
    public FooBarValidator()
    {

        RuleFor(x => x.FooBarNumber)
            .GreaterThan(0)
            .WithMessage("Field must be greater than zero");
         }
}
```

and `FooBarValidator` is not called.

Comment: Can you show your `FooBarValidator `

Answer (score 0):

I ended up iterating over each item in the List request and calling the .Validate() function on an instance of the FooBarValidator within the Controller method.